# Dynamic require in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, require

I'm requiring a library in NodeJS which has a self-invoking function, that results an error because it looks for an object which is not initialized at that moment .

I want to dynamically `require` this library when that object is initialized.

Is there any way to dynamically `require`/ load a library ?

This is the part of library required : 
https://github.com/sakren/node-google-maps/blob/develop/lib/Google.js#L5

Actually I want to require when the window object is present (client-side rendering).

So something like this :

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Map = require('./map.jsx');
var Common = require('../common/common');
var MapStatic = require('./map-static.jsx');

exports.type = function() {
    return 'map';
};

exports.jsx = function(data) {
    if (Common.isServerSide()) {
        return (<MapStatic data={data}/>);
    } else {
        return (
            <Map data={data}/>
        );
    }
};

exports.transform = require('./map-transform.js');
```

The reason the code looks weired is that I'm using react.

Comment: Is there some code you can show us to help better illustrate your problem?  You should just be able to require the library after you initialize the object.

Comment: @Brennan code added. I want to the library to be require if and only if the else statement is the branch to go.

Comment: `require()` is just a normal function.  You can call it inside an `if` statement if you want.  I really don't follow what the question is here beyond that.

Comment: To make it simple to understand , let me rephrase the problem : 

Let's assume that you have 2 files. `File A` requires `File B` in an else section of an if-else block which is never reached. In `File B` there's a self-invoking function , which its only job is to throw an error. So, on the server side, NodeJS , regardless of this fact that requiring `File B` can never be reached , runs through `File B` and throws an error.

Comment: Have you considered forking the repository and making the function not self invoking?  This would solve your issue I believe.

Answer (score 3):

In nodeJS require can be used anywhere at anytime whithout much limitations AFAIK.

Which error is thrown once you require at runtime ?
In your else branch.

Comment: When `map.jsx` is required, there's a self-invoking function in it that throws an error (it checks for something and it throws an error, nothing wrong with that). What I'm saying is that even if we put the require statement in the else section it will require it , although it's not supposed to. How can I make it not require it when it doesn't reach that part of the else-if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
requires = {}
function getter(key) {
  if(!requires[key]){
    requires[key] = require(key)
  }
  return requires[key]
}
```

Comment: from what I know, it's not possible to require on run time.

Comment: I have used similar code in apps to dynamically load routes for express. Here is a working example https://bitbucket.org/benjar12/forensiqwrapper/src/a53d5a325a21ffd0592414fa8cfd87cc2bc203f4/server/lib/router.js?at=master